# how to generate custom queries for parameters in an object inside an Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm new to using the Spring framework and I've got a small thing bugging me.

I have this entity

```
String var1; 
String var2; 
AnotherClass object; 
...
...
...
```

And in the DAO I've extended the JpaRepository. 
Nonetheless I know that I can write a method in my DAO like this `Entity findByVar1(String var1);` and it does the rest.

However I would like to know how to fetch results according to a particular variable inside my `AnotherClass` class. 
Like suppose `AnotherClass` contains 3 variables, and I want to fetch my results according to one or two of them. How will that work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try findByObject_anotherClassVar1(String anotherClassVar1) Here Object is the reference variable of AnotherClass

Answer (score 0):

You can find the way your child entity connected. Suppose there is field in `AnotherClass` named `var3` then the method will be

```
Entity findByObjectVar3(String var3);
```